# App crashes when using function of this package REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Im building a music player and I need to get all music files, to do that I'm using this package: [get-music-files](https://github.com/cinder92/react-native-get-music-files)

But there's a problem, the app crashes im my device when I run one of its method, this one:

```
MusicFiles.getAll({
        id : true,
        blured : false,
        artist : true,
        duration : true, //default : true
        cover : true, //default : true,
        title : true,
        cover : true,
        batchNumber : 5, //get 5 songs per batch
        minimumSongDuration : 10000, //in miliseconds,
        fields : ['title','artwork','duration','artist','genre','lyrics','albumTitle']
    });
```

And the expected output is this:

```
    [
   {
    id : 1,
    title : "La danza del fuego",
    author : "Mago de Oz",
    album : "Finisterra",
    genre : "Folk",
    duration : 132132312321, // miliseconds
    cover : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    blur : "file:///sdcard/0/123-blur.png", //Will come null if createBLur is set to false
    path : "/sdcard/0/la-danza-del-fuego.mp3"
  }
]
```

In the emulator it doesn't crash, but gives me an error `Something get wrong with musicCursor` while in my device in debug mode when I run the method the app crashes and close

If I don't enable these permissions in the emulator:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The app will crash as in the device, but if they are enable at least it will print the error but in the device with they enable it just crash, i also make sure in `AndroidManifest.xml` these permissions are in, what could be the problem? Maybe it's because this package is from two years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Also starting from Android M, users need to be prompted for permission dynamically. Follow this [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid) for more details on how to do that.

Comment: its already prompted and accepted, but the app crashes everytime i run that method